# JavaFX- cannot get custom button to print hello world

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I've been trying to get one of the buttons I have in a separate FXML file, to print "Hello" world after it is imported to my main scene. I am using scenebuilder and trying to separate the media button code from the rest of the application. t I've referred to numerous tutorials but, cannot see where I've gone wrong. Here are the relevant files (I left out some code to make it more readable):

From my main scene AudioPlayer.fxml(mediaBoxAnchor is the component that contains my non-functioning button):

```
<HBox layoutX="751.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="159.0" spacing="5.0" styleClass="head" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="751.0" layoutY="14.0" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Slider layoutX="196.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="828.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="195.0" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="mediaBoxAnchor" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="20.0">
         <children>
            <HBox fx:id="mediaControlHBox">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="previousButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Prev" />
                  <Button fx:id="playButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Play" />
                  <Button fx:id="nextButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
```

MediaPlaybackHBoxWidget:

```
public class MediaPlaybackHBoxWidget extends AnchorPane {

@FXML
private Button previousButton, playButton, nextButton;

public MediaPlaybackHBoxWidget() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("/fxml/MediaPlaybackHBox.fxml"));

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

   }
}
```

MediaPlaybackHBox.fxml:

```
<fx:root fx:id="mediaBoxAnchor" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.mavenproject1.MediaPlaybackHBoxController">
   <children>
      <HBox fx:id="mediaControlHBox">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="previousButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Prev" />
            <Button fx:id="playButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Play" />
            <Button fx:id="nextButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

MediaPlaybackHBoxController:

```
public class MediaPlaybackHBoxController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button previousButton, playButton, nextButton;

@FXML
MediaPlaybackHBoxWidget mpw;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Any clue as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I was going about this the wrong way. The controller section of Oracle's [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers), seems to be helpful.